# Table Creating in Toad

Tags: oracle, toad

To create a table I click on the create table icon shown in the picture here

[image: image 1]

When Click on the create table icon,then I found like this picture

[image: image 2]

I could not found name property there to create column.How can i find this?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Um, did you click the "Add Col" button?

Comment: i have done editing

Comment: I have clicked add column but getting no space or option to enter name

Comment: What about table name?

Comment: even after giving the table name,I could not found the option to enter name

Comment: Can't you use a DDL statement to achieve that??

Comment: Yes I can use DDL statement but I want to do it that way.

Comment: can you share when youu clicked add column button

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar  but getting no space or option to enter name

Comment: add_column button is broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in toad you can create table automatically,

you can create table like this;
[image]

As you see you can **fill column name after click add column button**

if you cant see this maybe your toad version is old or there is a bug on installation or something else.

my version is;
[image]

you can try **repair or re installation**